# jquery iterating over list element with on click event

Tags: jquery

I have a list that I want to attach a click onto for each li although i'm failing to get this working, example below.  please help!?
Thanks,

```
 <ul>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>c</li>
   <li>d</li>
 </ul>


 $('li').each(function () {
     $(this).click(function (e) {
        // access the letter - not sure how to do this (?)
     });
  });
```

Comment: While not the ideal syntax, your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UA72c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$(function(){
     $('li').click(function (e) {
        alert(this.innerHTML);  // not sure how to access this (?)
     });
});
```

You don't need to use each iteration on `li`. All you need is a selector while registering the click event and then access either with plain element propert `this.innerHTML` or jquery methods `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ELUVH/)**

Comment: for some reason the alert pops up multiple times?

Comment: @Aiias `this` is not jquery object $(this) is.

Comment: @Aiias `this` by default is not a jQuery object

Comment: @JamesRadford added a fiddle. See if that help you.

Comment: @JamesRadford are you adding them dynamically? can you replicate it in a fiddle? click is not getting invoked at all. Place it in document.ready. See my answer update

Comment: @JamesRadford - is your code wrapped in a document ready call?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    $(this).text(); 
 });
```